# navigateToURL, how to make it open new tab in browser instead of window (pop-up)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework, navigatetourl

I've got a flash game, which is sponsored, so I have several buttons in the game that lead to my sponsors website. I used the following code on each of them:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.sponsorsite.com"), "_blank");
```

Now, the problem is that every one of these buttons open up a new window which is most of the time and for most of the people getting blocked by their browser (or popup-blockers). One button however (the one button I got from my sponsor and load as an swf at runtime) is different, and instead of opening a new window it opens up a new tab, which never gets blocked.

I'm now trying for hours to emulate that buttons behaviour, but there really seems to be not difference. It uses the very same line of code as stated above. The only difference is that it was created in the Flash IDE, exported as a swf, and then imported into my game.

Do you have any idea how I can make 'navigateToURL' open up a new tab instead of new window in the users browser?

Comment: Why don't you try `ExternalInterface` and connect with browser?

Comment: Too complicated (for now), because I solved it already by having all my buttons imported as swfs. Thank you :) !

Comment: You can close the question if you've got the right answer, so it won't stay opened and unanswered :)